# scala deprecation warning with playframework and slick

Tags: scala, playframework, slick

Hi all I got this deprecation warning

in my playframework application with scala and slick

```
[warn] 
\app\dto\processTemplateDTO.scala:95: method columnToOptionColumn in trait API is deprecated: Use an explicit conversion to an Option column with `.?`
[warn]     def processtemplateFK: ForeignKeyQuery[ProcessTemplates, ProcessTemplatesModel] = foreignKey("Process", processtemplate, processTemplates)(_.id, onUpdate = ForeignKeyAction.Restrict, onDelete = ForeignKeyAction.Cascade)
```

can I just use .? instead of _.id

Thanks at all

Comment: Can you add your complete table code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what it is saying is that when writing your provenShape implementation you should lift your non-option column to optional using this:

```scala
case class Coffee(id: Option[Int],name: String)

class Coffees(tag: Tag) extends Table[Coffee]("coffees",tag){
  def id: Rep[Int] = column[Int]("id",O.AutoInc)
  def name: Rep[String] = column[String]("name")
  //see the .? method
  def *: ProvenShape[Coffee] = (id.?,name) <> (Coffee.tupled,Coffey.unapply) 
}
```

in your case try `"_.id.?"` but not sure why u'd want to have a nullable column as foreign key.